# Android memalloc

Tags: android, memory-management, android-canvas

What does the following line mean (taken from Android logs):

```
06-21 23:48:29.701: D/memalloc(5389): /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x52522000 size:3047424 offset:3031040 fd:76
```

Specifically, what does offset and fd stand for? One of my android apps (that draws some stuff onto a canvas) seems to hang when the fd reaches 86.

Comment: That looks interesting... I'd guess that 'fd' stands for 'filedescriptor', but unless your app opens a lot of files, I'm guessing it's not about memory mapped files. (file descripters are used for plenty of things that aren't files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer:** You're probably running out of memory.

**Long answer:** (This is highly speculative, using lots of guess work)

`PMEM` *is a module in android that handles allocating large chunks of contiguous physical memory*. 
Apparently it's also relevant to graphics, see

- http://www.slideshare.net/jserv/design-and-concepts-of-android-graphics
- http://www.slideshare.net/jserv/accel2drendering

This presentation is the best thing I could find, and it's sadly lacking in explanations.  
However, it does mention that various graphics related things in android use large buffers allocated via PMEM.

PMEM apparently creates a memory structure with several buffers inside one contiguous bloc*.
 
`base` is the (physical? mmaped virtual? I'm not sure) *base address of the entire PMEM buffer*. 
`Size` seems to refer to the *size of the indivial "sub block"*. 
`offset` gives the *start address of the specific "sub block"*  
 `fd`, or file descriptor, is used to *access* that specific buffer

Since you mention that values of `fd` above 86 lead to bad things, and the above example has fd = 76, I'm guessing you're simply running out of memory 
(PMEM can only handle 12 buffers, so maybe you're running into that limit, too?)